# What is masking doing to the padding in the encoder stage of transformer?

Tags: natural-language, transformers

I'm referring to this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422890/why-do-we-use-masking-for-padding-in-the-transformers-encoder)

What I don't understand is, if the result of padding is simply adding zeroes to ensure all input sequences are of the same length what is the masking stage doing exactly ?

Truncating would defeat the purpose of padding in the first place, and setting to zeros would be redundant as padding is already set to 0.

I don't quite understand what masking is doing.

Comment: The post that you link to directly addresses your question: we don't want the model to be influenced by the padding tokens. Therefore, the padding tokens are masked.

Comment: @Sycorax, I'm sorry but you're mistaken on my question. The post explain that masking is preventing the model form using the padding. But it does not explain what that means. Since the padding are already 0 what is the masking operations applied ?. This is not addressed in the referred post.

Comment: @Sycorax, also in this context we are talking about masking attention applied to the input to "ignore" padding during the tokenization. This is not the masking applied at the decoder stage.

Comment: The top-voted answers in the duplicate thread appear directly responsive to this question: "By setting the mask vector $M$ to a value close to negative infinity where we have padding tokens and 1 otherwise, we ensure that no attention is paid to those tokens." If you feel they are not, please [edit] to clarify (1) the exact part of the model you are asking about (the more detail the better) and (2) what you understand about how the model works and (3) what you are specifically interested in knowing about.

Comment: @Sycorax, thanks I'll try clarifying my question then. I appreciate you took the time to provide some answers.